# Evaluating $\int_0^{\infty} x^r \exp(e^{-s x}) e^{-ax^b}dx$

Tags: exponential-function, indefinite-integrals, special-functions, symbolic-computation

Can you analytically evaluate the integral
$$
\int_0^{\infty} x^r \exp(e^{-s x}) e^{-ax^b}dx,
$$
where $s,r,a,b>0$ are constants, $e$ is the exponential?

Comment: Try to be more spicific. Fully explain the notions and notations, provide the backround and your effort so far. I suggest you to check [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: $\exp (e^{-s x})$... really?  Did you just write down a hard integral and just ask others to solve it for you?  That's not how this site works.

Comment: Hi David, it's just a question, here we find questions such as "solve this", "prove that", with no  further explanation and people answer. I had expressed it in terms of h-function, but it was even worse, then I made it easier (I think). I would be happy with some ideas of how to start. If I get no answer, I will withdraw the post. Sorry for any inconvenience.